# Not able to install io module in python 3.4 on win10

Tags: python, io, pycurl

I'm trying to install the io module in python3.4 or in py 2.7 on my Win10 with

```
python -m pip install io
```

in order to use io.StringIO with pycurl but in both cases it says:

```
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement io (from versions: )
   No matching distribution found for io
```

I actually want to use curl with the GET method to access a https site on spotify 
and process the json result...

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to *install* `io`? That's a *standard library module*, you don't need to install it, it is already part of Python (from 2.6 onwards).

Answer (score 16):

You do not have to explicitly install [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html). It comes along with python bundle at the time of installing python. Within your code, just do:

```
import io
```

and it will work fine

Answer (score 8):

The `io` module is part of Python *already*. It is in the standard library from Python 2.6 onwards. See the [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) versions of the documentation.

In fact, there is no [`io` package on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/io) *to* install (the link gives a 404 not-found error).

Note that I expect pycurl to write *bytestrings*, not Unicode text. You probably want to use `io.BytesIO` instead here. See [Pycurl and io.StringIO - pycurl.error: (23, 'Failed writing body)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606447/pycurl-and-io-stringio-pycurl-error-23-failed-writing-body) and the [PyCurl documentation](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/unicode.html#writing-to-stringio-bytesio).